# Python: adding results in for loop

Tags: python

I want to add the inventory value of each and print out the new total:

```
prices = {
    "banana" : 4,
    "apple"  : 2,
    "orange" : 1.5,
    "pear"   : 3,
}
stock = {
    "banana" : 6,
    "apple"  : 0,
    "orange" : 32,
    "pear"   : 15,
}



for key in prices:
    total = 0
    inventory = (prices[key] * stock[key])
    print key 
    print "inventory value: %s" % (inventory)
    total = total + inventory

print total
```

Comment: put `total = 0` _outside_ your for loop or it's reset every time.

Comment: Use rather Counter from `collections`: `Counter(prices) + Counter(stock)`

Comment: http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user42_IuCPcQKD20_0.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move the total=0 out side the loop

```
prices = {
    "banana" : 4,
    "apple"  : 2,
    "orange" : 1.5,
    "pear"   : 3,
}
stock = {
    "banana" : 6,
    "apple"  : 0,
    "orange" : 32,
    "pear"   : 15,
}


total = 0
for key in prices:
    inventory = (prices[key] * stock[key])
    print key 
    print "inventory value: %s" % (inventory)
    total = total + inventory

print total
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is that you reset `total` at every iteration.

You could avoid those kind of errors by using comprehensions which ensure a proper control flow for those kind of problems:

```
total = sum(p * stock.get(key,0) for key,p in prices.items())
```

It is much faster than a classical loop (and iterating on both keys and items saves the access to the price item) and as a last bonus: tf item not in stock, doesn't crash but yields `0`

Comment: thanks this also worked and I didn't have to create the initial total variable and set it to 0.

Comment: what is the advantage of using this method as opposed to the simple solution of placing 'total = 0' outside of the for loop?

Comment: its pythonic - meaning its concise